# Add Profile Information in MyAccountController [backpack-laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I thought about adding a page, to change the profile of a user: name, surname, etc.

## Bug report

File: MyAccountController.php

function: public function postAccountProfileForm(UpdateRequest $request)
the FormRequest, returns empty

#### What I did:

**DB:**
users->Profiles

**File Controller: App\Http\Controllers\Auth\MyAccountController**

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use Backpack\Base\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\MyAccountController as BaseMyAccountController;
    use App\Http\Requests\Auth\Account_profileRequest as StoreRequest;
    use App\Http\Requests\Auth\Account_profileRequest as UpdateRequest;
    use Auth;
    use App\Models\Auth\Account_profile;

    class MyAccountController extends BaseMyAccountController
    {
        /**
         * Show the user a form to change his personal information.
         */
        public function getAccountProfileForm()
        {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $this->data['title'] = trans('backpack::base.my_account');
            $this->data['profile'] = Account_profile::getAccount_profilebyId($user->id);

            return view('backpack::auth.account.update_profile', $this->data);
        }

        /**
         * Save the modified personal information for a user.
         */
        public function postAccountProfileForm(UpdateRequest $request)
        {
            //var_dump($request);
            //die();
            //$result = $this->guard()->user()->update($request->except(['_token']));
            $result = Account_profile::getAccount_profilebyId($this->guard()->user()['id'])->update($request->except(['_token']));

            if ($result) {
                Alert::success(trans('backpack::base.account_updated'))->flash();
            } else {
                Alert::error(trans('backpack::base.error_saving'))->flash();
            }

            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

**File Request: App\Http\Requests\Auth\Account_profileRequest**

```
    namespace App\Http\Requests\Auth;
    use App\Http\Requests\Request;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

    class Account_profileRequest extends FormRequest
    {
        /**
         * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function authorize()
        {
            // only allow updates if the user is logged in
            return backpack_auth()->check();
        }

        /**
         * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
                // 'name' => 'required|min:5|max:255'
                'nome' => 'required|min:5|max:45',
                'cognome' => 'required|min:5|max:45',
                'sesso' => 'required|min:5|max:45',
                'countrys_id' => 'required|numeric',
                'regions_id' => 'required|numeric',
                //'provinces_id' => 'required|numeric',
                //'citys_id' => 'required|numeric',
                'users_id' => 'required|numeric',
                //'attivo' => 'required|boolean',
                //'accetto_condizionigenerali' => 'required|boolean',
                //'accetto_marketing' => 'required|boolean',
                //'attivo_notifiche' => 'required|boolean'
                //continue_13
            ];
        }

        /**
         * Get the validation attributes that apply to the request.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function attributes()
        {
            return [
                //
            ];
        }

        /**
         * Get the validation messages that apply to the request.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function messages()
        {
            return [
                //
            ];
        }
    }
```

**File Models: App\Models\Auth\Account_profile**

```
    namespace App\Models\Auth;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Backpack\CRUD\CrudTrait;

    use App\Models\Profile;

    class Account_profile extends Model
    {
        use CrudTrait;

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | GLOBAL VARIABLES
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | FUNCTIONS
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */
            public static function getAccount_profilebyId($id)
            {
                return Profile::find($id);
            }

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | RELATIONS
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | SCOPES
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | ACCESORS
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | MUTATORS
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */
    }
```

**File Route: Routes\backpack\Custom**

```
    // --------------------------
    // Custom Backpack Routes
    // --------------------------
    // This route file is loaded automatically by Backpack\Base.
    // Routes you generate using Backpack\Generators will be placed here.

    Route::group([
        'prefix'     => config('backpack.base.route_prefix', 'admin'),
        'middleware' => ['web', config('backpack.base.middleware_key', 'admin')],
        'namespace'  => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin',
    ], function () { // custom admin routes
    }); // this should be the absolute last line of this file


    Route::group(
    [
        'namespace'  => 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth',
        'middleware' => ['web', config('backpack.base.middleware_key', 'admin')],
        'prefix'     => config('backpack.base.route_prefix'),
    ],
    function () {
        // if not otherwise configured, setup the auth routes
        if (config('backpack.base.setup_auth_routes')) {
            // Authentication Routes...

        }

        // if not otherwise configured, setup the dashboard routes
        if (config('backpack.base.setup_dashboard_routes')) {
            Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard')->name('backpack.dashboard');
            Route::get('/', 'AdminController@redirect')->name('backpack');
        }

        // if not otherwise configured, setup the "my account" routes
        if (config('backpack.base.setup_my_account_routes')) {
            Route::get('edit-account-profile', 'MyAccountController@getAccountProfileForm')->name('backpack.account.profile');
            Route::post('edit-account-profile', 'MyAccountController@postAccountProfileForm');
        }
    });
```

**File Blade: resources\views\vendor\backpack\base\auth\account\update_profile.blade.php**

```
    @extends('backpack::layout')

    @section('after_styles')
    <style media="screen">
        .backpack-profile-form .required::after {
            content: ' *';
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
    @endsection

    @section('header')
    <section class="content-header">

        <h1>
            {{ trans('backpack::base.my_account') }}
        </h1>

        <ol class="breadcrumb">

            <li>
                <a href="{{ backpack_url() }}">{{ config('backpack.base.project_name') }}</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="{{ route('backpack.account.info') }}">{{ trans('backpack::base.my_account') }}</a>
            </li>

            <li class="active">
                {{ trans('backpack::base.update_account_info') }} Profile
            </li>

        </ol>

    </section>
    @endsection

    @section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @include('backpack::auth.account.sidemenu')
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">


            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-body backpack-profile-form">
                    {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'backpack.account.profile', 'method' => 'post')) !!}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @php
                            $label = 'Nome';
                            $field = 'nome';
                        @endphp
                        {!! Form::label($field, $label, ['class' => 'required']) !!}
                        {!! Form::text($field, old($field) ? old($field) : $profile->$field, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @php
                            $label = 'Cognome';
                            $field = 'cognome';
                        @endphp
                        {!! Form::label($field, $label, ['class' => 'required']) !!}
                        {!! Form::text($field, old($field) ? old($field) : $profile->$field, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @php
                            $label = 'Sex';
                            $field = 'sesso';
                        @endphp
                        {!! Form::label($field, $label, ['class' => 'required']) !!}
                        {!! Form::select($field, array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female'), old($field) ? old($field) : $profile->$field, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="box-footer">
                        @php
                            $field = 'id';
                            $label = '<span class="ladda-label"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>'.trans('backpack::base.save').'</span>';
                        @endphp
                        {!! Form::hidden($field, old($field) ? old($field) : $profile->$field) !!}
                        {!! Form::button($label, ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'type' => 'submit']) !!}
                        <a href="{{ backpack_url() }}" class="btn btn-default"><span class="ladda-label">{{ trans('backpack::base.cancel') }}</span></a>
                    </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

#### What I expected to happen:

I expect that the form is validated

#### What happened:

when I submit, the request returns to me empty

#### What I've already tried to fix it:

#### Backpack, Laravel, PHP, DB version:

Laravel Framework 5.7.12
"php": "^7.1.3"
"backpack/backupmanager": "^1.4"
"backpack/crud": "^3.4"
"backpack/langfilemanager": "^1.0"
"backpack/logmanager": "^2.3"
"backpack/newscrud": "^2.1"
"backpack/pagemanager": "^1.1"
"backpack/permissionmanager": "^3.12"
"backpack/settings": "^2.1"
"barryvdh/laravel-elfinder": "^0.4.1"
"fideloper/proxy": "^4.0"
"laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
"laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
"laravelcollective/html": "^5.7",
"mews/purifier": "^2.1",
"tymon/jwt-auth": "^0.5.12"

Comment: If you found a bug, then reporting it to the developers should probably be the best option you have.
According to [their documentation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.4/getting-started-license-and-support#support), they usually handle bug reports on [Backpack for Laravel's Github](https://github.com/laravel-backpack).


If you have some time left then, you can also read Stackoverflow's "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)".

Answer (score 0):

Do you told backpack to not setup auth routes so you can setup your own ?

Go ahead to `config/backpack/base.php` and change `setup_auth_routes` and `setup_my_account_routes` accordingly.

If you have your routes cached don't forget about `php artisan route:cache`

Best,
Pedro

Comment: Hi Pedro I solved, as soon as I migrate to version 4 of backpack, I make it public, hoping it could be of use to someone.